# how add hadoop jars to classpath?

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop 2.7.3 on my mac  is installed at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3
```

I write a demo to read file from HDFS using java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

public class HDFSTest{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{

  String file= "hdfs://localhost:9000/hw1/customer.tbl";
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(file), conf);
  Path path = new Path(file);
  FSDataInputStream in_stream = fs.open(path);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new      
  InputStreamReader(in_stream));
  String s;
     while ((s=in.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(s);
     }
    in.close();
    fs.close();
  }
}
```

When I compile the java file ,error as shown blow：

```
hero:Documents yaopan$ javac HDFSTest.java 
HDFSTest.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
                         ^
HDFSTest.java:10: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
                       ^
HDFSTest.java:12: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
                       ^
HDFSTest.java:14: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
```

I know the reason is can not find hadoop jars，how to configure that？
                           ^

Comment: You may find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390492/package-org-apache-hadoop-conf-does-not-exist-after-setting-classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add hadoop jars to classpath:

I install hbase using homebrew on `/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.2.2`,

add all jars under `/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.2.2/libexec/lib` to classpath:

1.edit .bash_profile

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

2.add classpath

```
   #set hbase lib path
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH://usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.2.2/libexec/lib/*
```

3. save and exit

   wq

Answer (score 1):

Locate a jar file named "`hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar`" under your installation (i.e `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3`) and set it in classpath or give it directly in the command line along with `javac`.

```
javac -cp "/PATH/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar" HDFSTest.java
```

(replace `PATH` with appropriate path)